# Activate Firefox tab in Greasemonkey/Javascript? Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, greasemonkey

I developed a greasemonkey script that refreshes a page and checks for certain updates. I would like to run this script in a tab and browse the internet in another tab, but then have the script automatically activate it's tab when an update is found.

Im not sure how clear that was, maybe this is better:

Tab 1 is running a greasemonkey script, refreshing every x seconds looking for the word "foo"

Tab 2 is browsing stackoverflow

-- Now on a refresh, the GM script finds the word "foo". This is when I want the tab focus to automatically shift from Tab 2 to Tab 1.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're scraping stackoverflow for fresh questions, here's a hint: the RSS feeds for the tag of your choice are much smaller and easier to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that firefox gives focus to tabs that call `alert()`. So just pop up an
`alert('found foo')`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scriptish/)'s [`GM_openInTab`](https://github.com/erikvold/scriptish/wiki/GM_openInTab) implementation, like so:

```
GM_openInTab(window.location.href, true);
```

That should cause the page that a GM script is on to be focused.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [GM_openInTab()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_openInTab)?